# Как вывести на экран достижения, которые были получены?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы в конце уровня все достижения, значения которых были изменены, выводились на экран.
Так я сохраняю информацию о достижениях, которые были получены:

```
// вот эти ачивки будут создаваться в меню выигрыша. Функция вызывается при получении ачивки (ПЕРЕД изменением значения)
    public void LoadAchievementStartInfo(string title, int startAchievementValue, int startCounterAchievement, int ranking)
    {
        if (!achievementsChange.Contains (title))
        {
            achievementsChange.Add (title); // тут List<string>
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("StartAchievementValue" + title, startAchievementValue);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("StartCounterAchievement" + title, startCounterAchievement);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Ranking" + title, ranking);
        }
    }
```

Суть в том, что я для каждой ачивки сохраняю ее имя (`title`), "начальное значение до ее получения", еще одно "начальное значение" (для вопроса оно не важно, просто не стал строку удалять), а так же сохраняю ее позицию (`ranking`) - ее я хочу использовать для сортировки. Эта функция вызывается в `PlayScene` (соответственно, `achievementsChange` тоже находится там), а экран выигрыша - уже другая сцена.

И вот тут я начинаю дико тупить - как мне вывести на экран все ачивки, которые я таким образом сохранил?

Вообще для создания ачивки у меня есть функция `CreateAchievement (title, ну и всякие параметры)`, и вот как-то нужно создать все ачивки, которые были изменены, используя эту функцию (вернее, поместить информацию о достижениях в эту функцию).
Как-то так (просто чтобы пояснить идею):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < achievementsChange.count (как её получить?); i ++)
CreateAchievement(achievementChange[i], PlayerPref.GetInt("StartCounterAchievement" + achievementChange[i]), таким же образом остальные параметры);
```

Но ещё раз - я дико туплю, так как, возможно, только что написал решение 0_о

Вопрос несколько изменился: как мне перенести `achievementChange` (напомню, это `List<string>`) с имеющимися значениями из одной сцены в другую? Технически мне все ещё нужно получить ответ на тему вопроса, так что вроде нарушения правил нет.

---

Обновление:
Возможно, я не совсем корректно сформулировал вопрос. Достижения уже реализованы и они прекрасно работают. Мне для сцены выигрыша нужно отловить те достижения, которые были изменены (все достижения, которые были получены в процессе игры, а так же все достижения, значения которых были изменены - например, для одной ачивки прогресс 0/3, а в процессе игры я делаю 2/3; вот такие тоже нужно отлавливать), а затем вывести их на экран

Answer (score 0):

Абсолютное большинство игр грешат использованием [статичных классов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) и/или [синглтонов](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/2.3.php)
В Unity есть свои подводные камни. Поэтому реализация одиночки, зачастую, включает в себя вызов метода `DontDestroyOnLoad`. Подробнее можешь прочитать [здесь](http://unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=1198)

В любом случае, передавать `List<string>` - это плохая идея. Затем тебе понадобится отобразить прогресс достижения. И появится ещё один `List<int>`. Создай класс, описывающий достижение, помести его в глобальную коллекцию ачивок (`Dictionary<id,AchievementData>`), доступную из любой сцены. В качестве `id` можешь и дальше использовать string, или перейти на числа/GUID. Строки опасны тем, что имеют обыкновение по самым разным причинам меняться (рефакторинг, локализация), после чего перестают совпадать. Зачем эта головная боль?

Comment: Достижения уже реализованы и они прекрасно работают. Мне для сцены выигрыша нужно отловить те достижения, которые были изменены (все достижения, которые были получены в процессе игры, а так же все достижения, значения которых были изменены - например, для одной ачивки прогресс 0/3, а в процессе игры я делаю 2/3; вот такие тоже нужно отлавливать), а затем вывести их на экран

Comment: Ответ ты получил, а прислушиваться к рекомендациям или нет - дело твоё.

Comment: зачем мне делать еще один `Dictionary` (у меня он уже есть, в нем как раз и описаны все ачивки)? Я так понимаю, что, если я сделаю еще один такой, то он будет "затратнее", чем простой `List<>`, в котором простая строка/число в качестве `id`. "Создай класс, описывающий достижение, помести его в глобальную коллекцию ачивок (Dictionary<id,AchievementData>), доступную из любой сцены" - это все сделано. Или вы предлагаете в этом глобальном классе отлавливать `id` ачивок, которые были изменены?

Comment: @KremSoda автор, отвлекись от своих мыслей и перечитай первый абзац ответа. Если с этой проблемой разобрались и хочется поговорить за коллекции, то "простой `List<>`" будет затратнее, если по нему постоянно идти полнотекстовым поиском, как это делаешь ты, вызывая `.Contains`. Речь же идёт о том, что ты творишь страшные вещи. Вместо того, чтобы собрать информацию о достижении в одном типе, описав все четыре поля, ты хранишь их, как 4 независимых пары ключ-значение в словаре, и чтобы получить к ним доступ тебе нужно знать склеить заголовок достижения с каким-то префиксом. Это не ООП.